# Using tabular in newenvironment for style sheet

Tags: packages, environments

What I'm trying to do:

Define an environment ''explanation'' in my style sheet that I can use in my documents. It should take the explanation text and label it with ''Explanation:'' on the left of the text and display the explanation text on the right.

My plan was to use tabular for that.

Here is what I thought the definition code should be:

```
\newenvironment{explanation}[1]
{\tabular{cc}}
 Explanation: & {#1}
{\\ \endtabular}
```

But this gives the error

```
Missing \begin{document}
```

on the line with the &.

I've also tried lots of variations of this and none compiled.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

My style sheet:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{postenStyleSheet}[2020/06/28 Posten style LaTeX package]
\newenvironment{explanation}[1]
{\tabular{cc}}
 Explanation: & {#1}
{\\ \endtabular}
```

My latex document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{postenStyleSheet}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}\Huge{Title}\end{center}

\begin{explanation}{
this is an explanation Bla bla bla bla bla
$ 2 + 6 : 3 = 2 + (6 : 3) = 2 + 2 $
\end{explanation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete (compilable) code for what you've tried. No one can debug what has no code.

Comment: What should happen if the text part is longer than the linewidth? Please ahow a sketch of the desired output. Probably a customized description list is better suited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just define a new command, *\explain{text}*, that prints "Explanation:" to the left of *text* using a tabular environment. To ensure text wrapping, use a paragraph alignment option for column 2, e.g., m{10cm}.

You may find the LaTeX Wikibooks entry on defining new environments and commands useful if you require something more complex: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
  
\newcommand{\explain}[1]{
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{lm{10cm}} %define paragraph alignment option for text wrapping in column 2
         Explanation: & {#1} \\
    \end{tabular}
\\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Huge{Title}\end{center}
    
\explain{This is an explanation. Bla bla bla bla bla.}

\explain{$2 + 6 : 3 = 2 + (6 : 3) = 2 + 2$}

\explain{This is an example of a long entry that wraps once 
     the cell contents exceed 10cm.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That does exactly what I was trying to do! I'll use a command then instead of an environment.